# MSBuild UsingTask declaration with AssemblyFile pointing to dll of current project

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task

I have a project "Project1" in visual studio which contains a class that implements Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Task. I would like this task to execute after building Project1.

In the project file for "Project1" I have the following:

```
<UsingTask
    AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)bin\Debug\net462\Project1.dll" 
    TaskName="MyTask"/>

<Target Name="ExecuteMyTask" AfterTargets="Build">
    <MyTask/>
</Target>
```

When I build Project1 it tries to execute MyTask after the build, but it seems that it can't find Project1.dll (even though after building it is there and the path is correct), giving an error along the lines of: "The "MyTask" task was not found"

If I then build a second time everything works fine, assuming because the dll is already there at the start of the process. It seems as if it tries to look for the dll before the build step even though the Target is declared with AfterTargets="Build".

How can I get this task to execute after the build?

Comment: When in the process do you put the Project1.dll into `bin\debug\net462` folder?

Comment: Yes that's where it builds to. I know the path is correct because it finds it on the second build.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear in the question, the dll is the compiled output of Project1. I can't add a reference in a project to it's own dll

Comment: Why your output path is `bin\Debug\net462` instead of `bin\Debug`, I tried to use the task.dll in task project but it succeeds for the first time(I delete the bin and obj to make sure it's clear). I'm sure the `AfterTargets="Build"` can work for this situation. Could you share the content in csproj which sets the path of Project1.dll? Or maybe I share a simple sample which succeeds?

Comment: I think the output path is like that just because my target framework is net462. I can't see anything in the csproj which explicitly sets the output path, that's just where visual studio puts the dll. A simple sample which works would be helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196500/discussion-between-lance-li-msft-and-karl).

Comment: Hi Karl, any update for this issue? You can check the content of my .csproj in the chat, and we can discuss about the cause of this issue in it:)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the way `you copy the Project1.dll to bin\Debug\net462 folder` is setting the OutputPath. Cause the order in the build process is: `compile the code to .cs in obj folder`=> `copy the assembly from obj to bin folder`.I'm not sure if you have a third action like `using target or post-build event` to copy the assembly from `bin\Debug` to `bin\Debug\net462`, so first try doing this by setting `OutputPath` property.

And I'm sure if we defines the custom target with declaration `AfterTargets`, it can find the assembly when executing the target in most of time. But it may be affected by other factors: The assembly is too big, the machine is old or ... One thing to avoid this situation is to create a new project and then test. Also, make sure the location of your `<Using Task> and <Target>` are at the bottom of the .csproj.

**Note:** When the `<Using Task>` try to use the assembly, make sure it is not occupied by another process.